# Is it possible to use Mapstraction on an SSL website

Tags: ssl, geolocation, openlayers, leaflet, mapstraction

I have carried out quite a bit of searching but it seems that you can't use Mapstraction on a SSL website. Has anyone been able to do this or would Leaflet/OpenLayers be the best option using a SSL tile provider.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As mentioned in my reply to dez: Some of the script files for Mapstraction have hard coded http (non SSL) addresses to tile servers etc. My assumption was that non SSL content would be displayed/used on a secured page thus warnings appearing for users where they would have to agree allowing the content.

Answer (score 0):

Mapstraction isn't a library you use on its own, its an abstraction layer that you use with one of the actual providers e.g. Google, Yahoo, OpenLayers, etc. Mapstraction doesn't have a problem with SSL and neither do any of the supported providers to my knowledge. You just need to ensure you specify https in your script tags.

Comment: Thanks dez. Some of the script files for Mapstraction have hard coded http (non SSL) addresses to tile servers etc. My assumption was that non SSL content would be displayed/used on a secured page thus warnings appearing for users where they would have to agree allowing the content.

Comment: That's a good point, the default tile layers for a couple of the providers are coming from a non-https address. You are able to override the default tile layer and specify a https address instead however the default should probably be changed so I'll add it to the issues list.